# Error while creating a side bar navigation in Angular

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I am trying to create a dashboard in Angular. I am using angular material package to create it.

My code works, but I have a problem with side navigation. As you could see from the image below when i click the button, the width of the side menu is decreased. rather I wanted it to be for whole page. Can anyone give me a lead where I am going wrong

```
Code : Component.html

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary"> Menu </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Test Application</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

this is my ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-nav',
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-nav.component.css']
})
export class MainNavComponent {


  constructor() {}

}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you can create a working example here?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground

Comment: i have not used it before

Comment: you don't want scrollbar or what please explain briefly!

Comment: @deepbchudasama I want to extend the height. As you could see for some reason, the height of the sidebar is restricted. and I dont need the scrollbar